# How do you tell the version of Flash Player running in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, debug, adobe-flash, version, flash-player

I am getting an error trying to debug in Flex: it says to make sure I'm running the debugger version of Flash Player.

I downloaded it and installed it, but still am getting the error. But I wonder how in Chrome do I check which version of Flash is running?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This page:  http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/155/tn_15507.html will tell you which Flash version you're running, and whether or not it's a debug version of the player.

Comment: 7 years later and this still worked for me after trying for about an hour to get it working using loads of other sites :)

Answer (score 2):

Right click on a flash object and choose the last item from the menu, which is usually something like "About Adobe Flash Player X". It will take you to a web page that tells you the exact version you have installed.

Answer (score 0):

One more method: Navigate to `about:plugins`, and you'll see "Shockwave Flash" with a version listed.